# How do I prevent the user from clogging up my Scanner?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a simple coin toss game. The premise is very simple: the user gets to call heads or tails. The computer then flips a coin, informs the user of the toss outcome, and whether they guessed correctly.

As far as the code goes, inside a while-loop I first prompt the user for input, which I read in using my Scanner's nextLine(), and then I assign this to a String variable. Then I call feedback(), which displays "Processing" to the terminal window and calls the currently-executing Thread's sleep(). Then I check their guess, and if for some reason it's invalid, I display an appropriate message to the terminal window and set a boolean to true. The truth of this boolean is what enables the while-loop to continue running. Something I'm not pleased with is that inside the while-loop, after I read in their guess to a String and as feedback() is executing, I can still type things in and hit enter. Then, the next few times through the loop (provided flag is set to true at some point), it uses the things I typed in for the assignment input = reader.nextLine(). I was very surprised. I thought that when nextLine() is called, the Scanner would only read one line of input until the next time nextLine() is called (i.e. the next time through the loop). But instead, it seems to have kept track of all lines entered AFTER input = reader.nextLine(), when feedback() was executing. Here's my question: Is there a way to get the Scanner to only read in one line and have it ignore anything else the user types in until the next time you're actually prompting them for input? In other words, make the game fool-proof by preventing the user from entering uncalled-for input that clogs up the Scanner and occupies the while-loop for several passes? Following is the complete implementation of my game:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Random randy = new Random();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner( System.in );
        String input = "";
        int guess = 0; 
        boolean flag = true;

        System.out.println("Let's flip a coin!");

        while( flag )
        {
            flag = false;
            System.out.println("\fEnter 1 for heads, 2 for tails.");
            input = reader.nextLine();
            feedback("Processing");

            try
            {
                guess = Integer.parseInt( input );
            }
            catch( NumberFormatException e )
            {
                flag = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid!");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }

            if( !flag )
            {
                try
                {
                    receive( guess );
                }
                catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
                {
                    flag = true;
                    System.out.println( e );
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
            }
        }

        feedback("Flipping");
        int outcome = randy.nextInt(2) + 1;

        if( outcome == 1 )
        {
            System.out.print("Heads! ");

            if( guess == 1 )
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Tails! ");

            if( guess == 2 )
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void receive( int g )
    {
        if( g < 0 || g > 2 )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Guess must be 1 or 2.");
        }
    }

    public static void feedback( String message ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        String feedback = message;
        System.out.println("\f");

        for( int x = 0; x < 12; x++ )
        {
            if( x % 4 == 0 )
            {
                feedback = message;
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }

            System.out.println("\f" + feedback );
            feedback += ".";
            Thread.sleep(125);
        }

        System.out.print("\f");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (clog, scanner) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will just be to read and throw away anything in the scanner as you post the question. The scanner may have a method to clear it or seek to the end as an alternative approach to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `reader.close()` when you're finished using the Scanner.

Add it here:

```
        try
        {
            guess = Integer.parseInt( input );
            reader.close();
        }
```

This will close the Scanner and prevent further interaction from the user if the input is parsed correctly. The line will not be executed if `Integer.parseInt(input)` throws an exception.

Closing Scanners and other readers/writers is good practice as it releases memory back to the system and prevents mishaps like that of your program.